# 2 Drupal Multisites, Separate Databases, Changing 1 Also Changes the Other

Tags: database, multi-sites, configuration

I have a very weird issue. Been doing Multisites in Drupal 7 for a while now without any hitches... until last week. I have 2 multisites both with separate databases, however when I change content on 1 of them it also changes content on the other.

I have *Multisite01 pointing to Database01* and *Multisite02 pointing to Database02* (copy of 01). I should be able to change 1 multisite and not have it effect the other. I'm not sharing databases or anything. This has always worked for me before.

What I did different in this instance was when I copied Database01, Database01-Copy, to create 02. I was in a hurry and meant to click on 01-Copy to rename but instead, I clicked on 01. No matter, or so I thought... I just renamed *Database01 to Database02* and then I renamed *Database01-Copy to Database01*.

Now Drupal has them permanetly linked... even if I link Multisite01 or 02 to another database (ie Database03 or 04, etc). So I know that the change is outside of each Multisite's database. Wondering if this can be fixed without reinstalling Drupal...

```
/*Misc. Info
Multisite01 Settings.PHP (Multisite02 is same but connects to database02)*/

$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'database01',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've been doing Multisites for awhile now, so this seems like an obvious question -- but did you clear the drupal cache?

... and after doing so, restart Apache.  Many of my "unexplainable" errors have come down to that.

Comment: I tried this too: http://tinyurl.com/bwg2vjo
But my sites.php looks more like this b/c of the URLs structuring the site.
$sites['subdomain.example.com.subdir.subdir'] = 'subdomain.example.com/subdir/subdir';